# android studio: help RecyclerView Click does not work

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to do a click event from `RecyclerView` in Main class, but it's not catching the click.

**Interface**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int posicao);
    void onItemLongClick(int posicao);
}
```

**interface attribute and setter**

```
private OnItemClickListener mlistener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mlistener = listener;
}
```

**class ViewHolder**

```
public class ViewHolderArtista extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ViewHolderArtista(@NonNull View itemView,  final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.onItemLongClick(position);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

implementing in class main:

```
artistaAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int posicao) {
        Log.d("TESTE", "CLIQUE CURTO" +posicao);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(int posicao) {
        Log.d("TESTE", "CLIQUE LONGO" +posicao);
    }
});
```

However, nothing happens when clicking:

[image: empty log when clicked]

that is, I am implementing the click event of RecyclerView in the main class, but it is not working, it does not catch the position of the clicked item.

Comment: @azurefrog see the question again so you can understand.

Comment: Have you tried passing the new `OnItemClickListener` to `artistaAdapter` in its constructor?  It looks like you only register the listener with the `View` there, and not in `SetOnItemClickListener()`.

Comment: @azurefrog yes I tried, but this way I find it more practical and easy because I just get the specific click event. Only that is not working, several tutorials do so and it works, except for mine :(

Comment: someone helppp?

Comment: Have you check if you're correctly send the listener?. Try commenting the `if (listener != null){`.

Comment: You should google search, It is popular [https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/]

Answer (score 0):

do not setOnClickListener in construct, instead, override onBindViewHolder function, setOnClickListener in it

Comment: if I use this method, how would I use it in the main class?

Comment: my intention is to use the click event in the main class or any other.

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT USE CLICK LISTENERS IN VIEWHOLDER CLASS**

it will always return null because it won't initialize.

Use click listeners in the recyclerview Adapter's onBindViewHolder() method.

Comment: if I use this method, how would I use it in the main class?

Comment: my intention is to use the click event in the main class or any other.

Comment: create adapter inside the main class and it should be easy to implement that

Comment: This is what I did as I showed in the question, but instantiating the adapter only shows the functions created in the ViewHolder and not in the onBindViewHolder. If you can be clearer, I thank you.

Comment: Let me guess you want to access main class when you perform click event right??.than create adapter inside the main activity. Than if you want to Access specific mathods or views you can get it

Comment: Forgive me, but I still do not understand. Could you exemplify?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as the others said by setting the listener in `onBindViewHolder`, or I have got a class for `recyclerView` actions as `onClick` and `onLongClick`.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

public class ItemClickSupport {
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                // ask the RecyclerView for the viewHolder of this view.
                // then use it to get the position for the adapter
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        }
    };
    private View.OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                return mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener mAttachListener
            = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            // every time a new child view is attached add click listeners to it
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            }
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    };

    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        // the ID must be declared in XML, used to avoid
        // replacing the ItemClickSupport without removing
        // the old one from the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
        // if there's already an ItemClickSupport attached
        // to this RecyclerView do not replace it, use it
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support != null) {
            support.detach(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemLongClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }

    public interface OnItemLongClickListener {

        boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }
}
```

> Don't forget to import `<package>.R`